# How to resolve unexpected token error when you have two lines in json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have content from server that i am downloading into file, so when i have multiple lines json i could not download the file i am getting unexpected token i believe this exception is because of new line character, How can i resolve this issue ?

data from server

```
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
```

ctrl.js

```
  $scope.downloadFile = function(message){
        DitFactory.getFile(message).then(function(response,$window){
            var data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'text.txt');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

error

```
angular.js:13708 SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 49
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson
```

Comment: Are these objects within an array? If so, comma is needed to separate them.

Comment: The data from your server is not valid JSON so you cannot parse it as JSON. As @developer033 said, you probably want to put those objects in a JSON array

Comment: i am getting file name and content from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid json response should look like this:

```
[
    {"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"},
    {"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"},
    {"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
]
```

Change your server response to return valid value.

**Otherwise**, parse the response like this if this:

```
var response = '{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}\n{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}\n{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}';


var items = response.split('\n');
items = items.filter(function(item) {
    return item
  })
  .map(function(item) {
    return angular.fromJson(item);
  });



console.log(items);
```

**Online Demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/H3tcxWqMUFep4n3LSt1C?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for the help it gives me better understanding where i need to make a fix. thanks again

Comment: For sure friend, do note that if you use the `$http` module and when the server returns valid json response (headers + content) then angular will automatically parse the json string into an object. read about the `$http` module to learn more